# Detect IPcamera with wifi in ios sdk

Tags: ios, wifi, ip-camera

I am working on project with IPcamera.
Where i have to search for the camera which is connected with the router of the wifi.

Now Do i have to follow the below steps:-
1)Check the Wifi network in my device.
2)Get the ip address of those network
3)And instead of cameraid use ipaddress of the camera.

Please advice me